# geoTIFF raster // random display errors only in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, rendering, display, opengl

Sometimes I experience display issues with geoTIFF in QGIS (also had this once in TatukGIS). Now i have a situation in latest  QGIS running on Linux KDE.
The image is kind of disturbed (s. example). If you move it it randomly gets different defects.

On another QGIS station it's shown perfectly. Also in other photo applications like GIMP, or even simple windows viewers.

What might be the reason? Looks like a rendering, or openGL issue or something like that.

[image]

---

The whole orthophoto is tiled and here's the gdal info about one tile as example:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: K:\ART_S40-S41_GK4\ART_S40-S41-4-2.tif
Size is 11000, 10500
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4",
    GEOGCS["DHDN",
        DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
            SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128000033,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
            TOWGS84[598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6314"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4314"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",12],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31468"]]
Origin = (4469187.435404540039599,5334060.089342270046473)
Pixel Size = (0.000631639000028,-0.000631639000028)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 4469187.435, 5334060.089) ( 11d35' 9.21"E, 48d 8'41.06"N)
Lower Left  ( 4469187.435, 5334053.457) ( 11d35' 9.22"E, 48d 8'40.84"N)
Upper Right ( 4469194.383, 5334060.089) ( 11d35' 9.55"E, 48d 8'41.06"N)
Lower Right ( 4469194.383, 5334053.457) ( 11d35' 9.55"E, 48d 8'40.85"N)
Center      ( 4469190.909, 5334056.773) ( 11d35' 9.38"E, 48d 8'40.95"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Unit Type: metre
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Unit Type: metre
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Unit Type: metre
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Unit Type: metre
```

Comment: Add gdalinfo report of your raster, even better if you can put a small test image available somewhere.